# Oracle LISTAGG and Coalesce

Tags: oracle, left-join, case, coalesce, listagg

I have the following table `EPS_PROPOSAL_EXT_T` that I've condensed:

```
+--------------------+------------+------------+
| PROPOSAL_NUMBER    |ONR_OPTION_1|ONR_Option_2|   ...
+--------------------+------------+------------+
|        1234        |      N     |      N     |   ...
|        1235        |      Y     |      Y     |   ...
|        1236        |      N     |      Y     |   ... 
+--------------------+------------+------------+
```

The problem here is that I need to do a `LISTAGG` across all those different ONR_Options, but I can't have them show up as `'Y'`.  I need to replace the ones that are `'Y'` with something human understandable.  See `SELECT` statement below where I've attempted to do this:

```
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER, eps.TITLE, per.FULL_NAME, ext.NRP_IREF_CD, ext.RESEARCH_TYPE_CD, 
nsf.NSF_CODE, ext.NPS_THRUST_DESCRIPTION,
   CASE
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_1 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 1'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_2 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 2'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_3 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 3'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_4 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 4'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_5 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 5'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_6 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 6'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_7 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 7'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_8 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 8'
        WHEN ext.ONR_Option_9 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 9' 
        WHEN ext.ONR_NOT_APPLICABLE = 'Y' THEN 'Not Applicable'
        ELSE ''
   END ONR
FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROPOSAL_EXT_T ext
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = ext.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON per
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = per.PROPOSAL_NUMBER AND
      (per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD')
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_ABSTRACT abs
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = abs.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN NSF_CODES nsf
    ON eps.NSF_CODE = nsf.NSF_SEQUENCE_NUMBER
WHERE eps.OWNED_BY_UNIT = '401' AND eps.requested_start_date_initial >= DATE '2019-10-01';
```

This works but you can see the problem with it, right?  The way I've setup my `CASE` statement, it will not take into account when for a particular PROPOSAL_NUMBER there is more than one ONR_Option that is `TRUE`.

In the example I gave above, if I search for a proposal with number = 1235; the `ONR` result should be - 'Option 1, Option 2'.

How do I solve this dilemma with `LISTAGG` and `COALESCE`?  Or is that the way to go about this?

Comment: Do you have fixed options of `9` and '1' for not applicable ?how the options are stored in `EPS_PROPOSAL_EXT_T` ? Is it at column level or row level ?

Comment: Options are stored at the row level - you can look them up via PROPOSAL_NUMBER.  At the application level, if someone selects "Not Applicable" - all options automatically get false values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LISTAGG` doesn't help here. Why? Because your data model is **wrong**. In my opinion, should be something like this:

```
SQL> with test (prop, onr, status) as
  2    (select 1234, '1', 'N' from dual union all
  3     select 1234, '2', 'N' from dual union all
  4     select 1234, '3', 'Y' from dual union all
  5     select 1235, '1', 'Y' from dual union all
  6     select 1235, '2', 'Y' from dual union all
  7     select 1235, '3', 'N' from dual
  8    )
  9  select prop,
 10    listagg(case when status = 'Y' then 'Option ' || onr end, ',')
 11      within group (order by onr) as result
 12  from test
 13  group by prop;

      PROP RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
      1234 Option 3
      1235 Option 1,Option 2

SQL>
```

---

The way it currently is, see if this - concatenation of as many `CASE`s as there are `ONR_OPTION` columns in the table, which scales as a goat you'd like to teach to fly,  along with pain of removing multiple commas -  helps:

```
SQL> with test (prop, onr_1, onr_2, onr_3) as
  2    (select 1234, 'N', 'N', 'Y' from dual union all
  3     select 1235, 'Y', 'Y', 'N' from dual
  4    )
  5  select prop,
  6    trim(both ',' from
  7          case when onr_1 = 'Y' then 'Option 1' else null end ||','||
  8          case when onr_2 = 'Y' then 'Option 2' else null end ||','||
  9          case when onr_3 = 'Y' then 'Option 3' else null end
 10         ) as result
 11  from test;

      PROP RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
      1234 Option 3
      1235 Option 1,Option 2

SQL>
```